# Why do we use open sets for outer measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The standard definition for outer measure of a set of real numbers $A$ is:

$$ m*(A) = inf {\Large \{} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell(I_k) \; {\Large |} \; A \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k {\Large \}} $$

(as, for example, in Royden, Real Analysis, 4th ed., p. 31) where the $I_k$ are required to be nonempty, *open*, bounded intervals.

My question is: Would it amount to the same thing if we instead required that the $I_k$ are nonempty, *closed*, bounded intervals? It feels like there should be some reason why inner measure uses closed sets and outer measure uses open sets, but I can't think of an example set $A$ where $m*(A)$ would differ from $m**(A)$ defined exactly as above except that each $I_k$ is required to be closed.

Comment: Mama Rudin has no 4th edition, I guess you cite Royden & Fitzpatrick.

Comment: Also related: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Measure_Theory/Riesz%27_representation_theorem. This follows the proof in Mama Rudin.

Comment: This is not "the standard definition of outer measure". You don't even need a topology to define outer measure. You have a collection of sets where the measure is defined and you want to extend it. Open sets have the nice property that whenever they cover a compact set, you do have a finite sub-cover.

Comment: I see no problem in allowing empty and unbounded intervals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we replace $I_k$ with $\bar I_k$ then $l(I_k)=l(\bar I_k).$ On the other hand if $ G=\{J_k :k\in N\}$ is a set of closed bounded intervals with $A\subset \cup G,$ then for any $e>0$ we can cover each $J_k$ with a bounded open interval $I_k$ with $l(I_k)<e 2^{-k}+l(J_k)$. So $m*=m**$. It is a matter of convenience. For example with the usual def'ns of outer measure $m^o$ and inner measure $m^i$ it is fairly obvious that if $A$ is a bounded interval and $B\subset A$ then $m^i(B)+m^o(A\backslash B)=l(A)$.

Comment: Your argument shows that my $m*(A)$ and $m**(A)$ take the same values, so that's a big part of the answer I was looking for. I guess using open for outer and closed for inner makes it more difficult to fit. So, it becomes non-trivial that a countable set of points has measure 0. If we used closed sets for outer measure, it would be immediate because we just take each point $a$ as covered by $[a, a]$. And it would follow immediately that the rationals have measure 0. Also not sure whether it's relevant, but Heine-Borel gives finite subcovers only for collections of open sets.

Answer (score 2):

It may have something to do with the fact that an open set is the union of countably many open intervals, and thus the outer measure can be defined as the infimum of the measures of open supersets, whereas a closed set is not necessarily the union of countably many closed intervals and points (the Cantor set is a counterexample).